# Surface measure of $A={\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:z=f(x,y),x^2+y^2<1}\}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ f\in C^{\infty}$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $1$ and $$A={\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:z=f(x,y),x^2+y^2<1}\}.$$ Why does it imply that $\sigma_2$ measure of set $A$ is between  $\pi$ and $\pi\sqrt{3}$? And why isn't for every $c\in\mathbb{R}\ \ A\cap\{z=c\}$ one-dimensional manifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area formula states that (writing $\sigma_2(A)$ for the area of $A$:
$$
\sigma_2(A) = \int_{x^2+y^2<1} \sqrt{1 + |\nabla f|^2} \,dx\,dy.
$$
Since $1\leq 1 + |\nabla f|^2\leq 3$ (by the Lipschitz condition on $f$).  This
gives the bound $\pi \leq \sigma_2(A) \leq \sqrt{3}\pi$.

Furthermore, suppose $f = 1$ for all $x^2+y^2 < 1/2$. Then $A\cap{z=1}$ is not
a one-dimensional manifold.  However, for almost all $c$, you do have that $A\cap {z=c}$ is a one-dimensional manifold.  (By a Sard-type theorem).